# Git commit not working with message

Tags: git, github

Sending commit message giving error `pathspec did not match`. I am already using double quotes instead of single quotes.
[image]

Update When I do a commit without message I get this -

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
```

Comment: Have you staged your changes before trying to commit?

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: check git status first.

Comment: `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following:

1. check to see if added anything for to commit
2. git commit (without message) to see if you get the commit editor
3. try to execute the commands vi git bash instead of CMD.
4. Check to see if you have renamed any file on the file system and not via `git mv`

Comment: I did a git status and there are tons of changes to be commited `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`

Comment: This is why you get this message, you need to add & commit your changes. to add all your files you can use `git add -A`

Comment: `git add .` doesn't add renamed files nut only the modified ones. if you want them both  you will need to use `git add -A` which is alias for `git add . && git add -u`

Answer (score 0):

It's not git its a windows cmdline thing

Use 2x double quotes to solve the issue

git commit -m "" your commit message ""